# Работа с ресурсами с++ WinApi

Tags: c++, ресурсы

Объясните пожалуйста, как работать с ресурсами в с++. Насколько я понимаю, нужно создать файл с расширением .rc. И что дальше? Видел, что написан он не на Си, а на другом языке. Как в него впихнуть .png, скажем, и как в процессе работать с этим .png-ом, то есть с ресурсом, в общем объясните, ибо нигде не могу найти нормальной инфы по этой теме.
Работаю в VS 2015, с "чистым" WinApi

Comment: Файл нужно добавить в проект через контекстное меню проекта, таким образом скомпилированный екзешник будет его содержать в себе. Если проект создавать как "Windows application", то файл `.rc` создастся сам, и туда автоматически будут добавляться все ресурсы. Загружать их можно через `LoadResource();`

Comment: @YuriyOrlov Почитал, что функция возвращает HGLOBAL.Что мне с ним делать?Путь к файлу указывать как-то через HRSRS? Можно с кодом, по-подробней, пожалуйста .

Comment: @АртурКлочко если бы вы пробовали читать документацию на LoadResource(), вы бы увидели что параметр hResInfo получается через FindResource(Ex)

Answer (score 2):

Для получания вашего файла-ресурса побайтно можно использовать примерно такой кусок кода

```
HMODULE handle = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
HRSRC rc = FindResource(handle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(name), MAKEINTRESOURCE(type));
HGLOBAL rcData = LoadResource(handle, rc);
DWORD size = SizeofResource(handle, rc);
const char *data = static_cast<const char *>(LockResource(rcData));
```

где `name` и `type` берутся как раз из файла `.rc`, в результате содержимое будет доступно через `data`

Comment: Я немного разобрался. Когда я добавляю, допустим .png через редактор ресурсов, автоматически создаётся resource.h, в котором будет IDB_PNG1(его использовать как name, правильно?А type тогда просто PNG?).То есть MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_PNG1)? А как получить из HGLOBAL HBITMAP или что-то из этой оперы?

Comment: `HBITMAP` можно получить только из файла `.bmp`, соответственно методом `LoadBitmap()`

Comment: а сам механизм получения ресурса я правильно понял?

Comment: `name` - да, а `type` - нужно смотреть что вы в `.rc` записали, там будет строка `IDB_PNG1 RESOURCE_TYPE "path_to_resource"`. В вашем случае скорее всего `RESOURCE_TYPE` будет `BITMAP`

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался) Но я нашёл способ загружать с помощью GDI+ : Bitmap bt(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)). Буду искать, как загружать другие ресурсы с помощью GDI+(PNG,JPG,GIF). Ещё раз спасибо